# C#: Datagrid to Excel .Cell border is missing in the created excel file

Tags: asp.net, excel, datagrid, export-to-excel

I am trying to create an excel file from datagrid in my asp.net page using the below code.I am able to create the excel file.But the created excel file does not has the cell borders.Without the cell borders,it looks like a word document.

[image]

My code is

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=asas.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        this.EnableViewState = false;
        System.IO.StringWriter oStringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter oHtmlTextWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter);
        this.ClearControls(dgShipping);
        dgShipping.AllowPaging = false;
        DisplayRecords();
        dgShipping.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);
        Response.Write(oStringWriter.ToString());
        Response.End();
        dgShipping.AllowPaging = true;
```

Any workarounds for this ? Thanks for help

Comment: are you using a xls template?

Comment: no.Why should i use a template in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following `2 Lines` after "RenderControl" Line. It will resolve your issue and grid lines will be added.

```
string style = @"<style> TABLE { border: 1px solid red; } TD { border: 1px solid red; } </style> ";
Response.Write(style);
```

Change the color and line thickness as per your requirements.